# Is this construction forced to be an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

### Definitions:

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category, and let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be objects in $\mathbf{C}$. Let $F:A \rightarrow B$ and $F': B \rightarrow A$ be morphisms such that $F \circ F'$ and $F' \circ F$ are isomorphisms on $B$ and $A$ respectively. Similarly, let $G:B \rightarrow C$ and $G': C \rightarrow B$ be morphisms such that $G \circ G'$ and $G' \circ G$ are isomorphisms on $C$ and $B$ respectively.

### Question:

Given the above definitions, is $F' \circ G' \circ G \circ  F$ forced to be an isomorphism?

### Additional Notes:

1. Question inspired by Exercise 5.3.4.6 from [this](http://category-theory.mitpress.mit.edu/chapter005.html) document (Category Theory for the Sciences, by David Spivak).
2. Hints are better than complete proofs. Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: Prove that each of $F$, $G $, $F'$ and $G'$ is an isomorphism. (Hint for that: left invertible & right invertible $\Longrightarrow  $ invertible.)

Comment: Great! I can prove that each of these are both right and left invertible easily. And, as you say, it turns out this means each of these is invertible, and is thus an isomorphism. Finally, the composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism, completing the proof.